# How do I construct an isolated Screen with only State and Actions without it recomposing the entire function when the State changes?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a certain way of organising my files and "components" in a Screen: Route, Screen, ViewModel, State, Event and Actions.
Basically `Route` is the navigation, and `Screen` is only the @Composable UI.

In `Route` I grab the state from a StateFlow in the ViewModel

```kotlin
// FeatureRoute (Navigation)
...
composable("feature") {
   val viewModel: FeatureViewModel = hiltViewModel()
   val state by viewModel.stateFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
   FeatureScreen(state = state, actions = viewModel) // ViewModel implements interface FeatureActions
   // More things happen here; collecting events and navigation
}
```

It's a pattern I've grown attached to because it separates things really nicely.
Now, I am not super sure on how recomposition works and should happen.

Let's assume I have a Screen with some Composables in it and a CoolButton. This CoolButton is a Button with a label of `name` and on click it calls `onChange: (String) -> Unit` with a value of `name + "ABC".random()`. The ViewModel will receive the new String and updates the state on the StateFlow.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun FeatureScreen(
    state: FeatureState,
    actions: FeatureActions
){
    Column {
        Text(text = stringResource(R.string.staticString))
        Text(text = "Another Static String")
        CoolButton(
            name = state.name,
            onChange = { actions.updateName(it) }
        )
    }
}
```

Every time the button is pressed the `State(name: String)` will change and the entire `FeatureScreen(state, actions)` will recompose. i.e I can see in the Layout Inspector that Composables that doesn't depend on State also recomposes.

Question time:

- Is it wrong that the entire "Screen" recomposes?
- Can Screen recomposition be avoided?
- Is it wrong/bad to collect state and pass it into Screen, instead of collecting in the function? Will there be a difference?
- How can I make it so that only the child Composables that care's about the state of State recomposes?